# Similarity of matrices and sums

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> If $A$, $B$, $C$ are three $n \times n$ matrices and $A \sim B$, is $A - C \sim B - C$? In what cases does this hold?

This doesn't hold in general does it? But could it hold for some special cases?

Comment: A sufficient condition is if $C$ is a scalar matrix. It's not clear to me what answer the question is looking for, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar to one another, so there is an invertible $P$ such that $$PAP^{-1}=B.$$ Now, if $P$ commutes with $C$, then $$P(A-C)P^{-1}=PAP^{-1}-PCP^{-1}=B-C.$$ In particular, if $C$ is a scalar matrix, this will always work.